# Working with dictionary key:value pairs using prototype inheritance within a Jquery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am working on a plugin and I keep running into an error saying two of my customizable options `transitionValue` & `selector` are not defined. I have extended the options within the `TransitionCore` constructor  then my `TransitionCore.prototype` should have inherited my values. Moving along within my `TransitionCore.prototype` my functions`transitionFunc` I have made the calls using `defaults[selector]`, and `defaults[transitionValue]` in an effort to call the values from the dictionary I have created to use the options values. So to my understanding it should refer to the objects I created and source in the values. But that seems not to be the case. What I am doing wrong?

Thank you for the help!

```
;(function ( $, document, window ) {


var transitionScroll = 'transitionScrollPlugin',
    defaults = {
        transitionValue:100,
        selector:"$('[data-show*='on-scroll']')"
    };

// The actual plugin constructor
function TransitionCore( element, options ) {
    this.element = element;

    // jQuery has an extend method that merges the
    // contents of two or more objects, storing the
    // result in the first object. The first object
    // is generally empty because we don't want to alter
    // the default options for future instances of the plugin
    this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options);

    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = transitionScroll;

    this.init(); //method to initialize Plugin
}


$.extend(TransitionCore.prototype, {

    init: function()  {
        this.transitionFunc(this.element, this.options);
    },

    transitionFunc:function() {
         this._defaults[selector].each(function() { 
            this._defaults[selector].css("transition-delay", this._defaults[transitionValue] + "ms", this._defaults[transitionValue] += 100);
        });
    }

});

// A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor,
// preventing against multiple instantiations
$.fn[transitionScroll] = function ( options ) {
    return this.each(function () {
        if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + transitionScroll)) {
            $.data(this, "plugin_" + transitionScroll,
            new TransitionCore( this, options ));
        }
    });
};



})( jQuery, document, window );
```